# ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 cannot connect to USB tethering but windows10 can. (HELP)

Tags: tethering

I'm new in Linux please don't laugh at me. I have Samsung galaxy s9 and I'm using mobile data on wifi and decide to try USB tethering on windows its work perfect I get IP 192.168.42.124/24 and gateway 192.168.42.128, but in Linux ubuntu 18.04 is not cannot connect to phone I try static IP still, macchanger, (Clockworkmod USB problem in segmentation), easytether connect with some strange IP 192.168.117.0/24 and again no internet on the phone I try with USB Debug and without still no internet and cannot connect to phone.
remove mac address in Identity not help.
Linux Mint also cannot connect but windows don't have a problem with USB tethering even in VM.
Now I'm on ubuntu 20.04 from two days and still cannot connect.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug in the Samsung S9 firmware since April.

See:
https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S9/USB-Tethering-not-working-April-Update/td-p/1218731#

Comment: But it's working fine in windows and I get the IP address 192.168.42.127 or 128 so DHCP it's work I cannot start it on Ubuntu and other Linux distro.

Comment: Hi Aleksander!

Have you any progress with the latest firmware G960FXXU9ETF2 for Samsung Galaxy S9?

In my case USB tethering work again.

Comment: After update to G960FOXM9ETF2 it fixes the problem. Thank you for your replay.